# from design perspective, why aren't the error messages in eager and in graph mode the same in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Why aren't the error messages in eager and in graph mode the same in Tensorflow?

For instance:
running in eager mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
a = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2, 3])
a_tile = tf.tile(a, [5])
print(a_tile)
```

yields the error message:

```
Expected multiples argument to be a vector of length 2 but got length 1 [Op:Tile]
```

While running in graph mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2, 3])
a_tile = tf.tile(a, [5])

sess = tf.Session()
r1 = sess.run(a_tile)
print(r1)
```

yields the error message:

```
Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'Tile' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [2,3], [1].
```

While this might seems as a nuance, in some cases the error message in one (e.g. eager) is not precisely indicating the actual error, for instance for tf.linspace ([github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21391)).
Related to this, is a different behavior between eager and graph modes, not just in the error messages. For instance tf.while_loop ([github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21224)).

From a design perspective, how does eager mode was incorporated into the existing TF? I feel that understanding TF design can increase productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vast majority of code paths (such as the implementation of each operation) are exactly the same between eager and graph execution, but not all.

When not using eager execution, i.e., when using graphs - there is a distinct "graph construction" and "graph execution" (via `tf.Session.run`) phase. For example, consider this simple snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

element = tf.gather([1, 2], [10])
# No error till this point, error will be thrown when we execute the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(element))
```

When eager execution is enabled, the operation executes immediately and thus the error is raised earlier:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
element = tf.gather([1, 2], [10])
```

These delayed errors when building graphs can make things hard to use, so TensorFlow attempts to catch some errors at graph construction time by running additional checks - like shape validation. For every operation registered in TensorFlow (`REGISTER_OP` macro in C++), there is a [shape inference function](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#shape_functions_in_c) that validates the shapes of the inputs and produces the shapes of the outputs as a function of the input shapes. For example, see the [definition of the `Tile` operation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e240aa301afc57a63366638af4cf92c823e8084a/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc#L1722) (and [corresponding shape function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e240aa301afc57a63366638af4cf92c823e8084a/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc#L1728)).

These shape inference functions are meant to be in sync with the requirements of the operation, which will validate the requirements again at execution time. Ideally, these checks wouldn't have to be repeated between the kernel and the shape inference function, and the error messages would be the same. However, in practice, these checks are repeated (once at graph construction time, once at graph execution time) and the error messages are not always in sync.

When eager execution is enabled, the shape inference functions (and corresponding checks) are skipped since they are redundant (the operation will make the necessary checks anyway). However, as you observed, this means that the error messages can be different - in the `tf.tile` example above, and I *think* the same holds for the [`tf.linspace` issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21391). Worth noting that in both cases, you'd get an error with the same code in both graph and eager - so the intent of debugging in eager and then executing the code as a graph should still hold - these quirks of these additional checks at graph construction time notwithstanding.

Hope that explains the design and the reason for the difference.
If the error message isn't helpful, I'd suggest filing a bug (or better yet sending a pull request) to improve it. In this particular case, it seems that the kernel implementation could provide a better error message [around here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/79422ab39b5fe0e1491abb8deabc7ecb5fd9f3a2/tensorflow/core/kernels/tile_ops.cc#L96).

Comment: Ash, thank you for the detailed response, this is very helpful and insightful. I wish some internal Google documentation would have been made public. I assume that it includes these details. Reading it could have been so helpful, after being curated in a reasonable order. I will have a look at making a pull request. Thanks so much !